# Structure of some $\pi$-separable groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\pi$ be a subset of primes dividing order of $G$.

Then $G$ is said to be $\pi$-separable if there is a series of subgroups $1<H_1<H_2\cdots < H_n=G$ such that $H_i$ is normal in $H_{i+1}$ and each successive quotient is either $\pi$-group or $\pi$'-group.

(One successive quotient can be $\pi$-group and other can be $\pi$'-group).

> Q. If $G$ is $p$-separable for every prime divisor $p$ of $|G|$ then what can be said about $G$?

The finite solvable groups are of this type (mentioned in question), but $S_n$ for $n\ge 5$ are not $2$-separable, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right and in fact your condition is equivalent to $G$ being solvable.

Comment: @DerekHolt that's only true if $\pi$ is all primes dividing $|G|$. In this case it's equivalent to the non-abelian composition factors of $G$ not being divisible by $p$ for all $p\in\pi$.

Comment: @Derek: Now its clear your assertion. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are precisely the groups whose non-abelian composition factors are not divisible by $p$ for any $p\in\pi$.

That this is sufficient is easy as a composition series is a series of the above description. That this is necessary is also easy, because any series of the above description can be refined to a composition series and must therefore contain for each somposition factor $N$ of $G$ some $H_i, H_{i+1}$ with $|N|$ dividing $|H_{i+1}/H_i|$.

Comment: Sorry; can you give example of a non-solvable group which satisfies first statement in your answer and is $p$-separable for every prime $p$ dividing $|G|$? What is $\pi$ in first sentence? [I am considering structure of groups which are $p$-separable every $p$ dividing $|G|$.]

Comment: I think $A_5\times C_7$ is $p$-separable for $p=2,3,5,7$, am I right?

Comment: I might have misunderstood the precise statement of your question. If $\pi$ is the set of all primes dividing $p$ then $G$ is solvable - this follows from what I've written as being solvable is equivalent to all composition factors being abelian. I interpreted $\pi$ as being a set of some (not necessarily all) primes dividing $|G|$.

Comment: So, $A_5\times C_7$ is not $2$-separable as $A_5$ is a non-abelian composition factor divisible by $2$, but it is $7$-separable.

Comment: oh, sorry! It was actually my misunderstanding. You are right - $A_5\times C_7$ is not $2$-separable, $3$-separable or $5$-separable; but it is $7$-separable.